# Mule 3.5 Oracle database configuration

Tags: oracle, mule, saxparseexception

I am trying to configure an Oracle database endpoint in Mule 3.5 CE version. Here is my configuration.

```
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" useXaTransactions="true"  doc:name="Oracle Configuration" dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="5" acquireIncrement="2"/>
</db:oracle-config>

<spring:beans>               
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown" name="Bean">
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <spring:property name="url" value="${oracle.jdbc.url}"/>
        <spring:property name="user" value="${oracle.jdbc.user}"/>
        <spring:property name="password" value="${oracle.jdbc.password}"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

When I try to run it in Anypoint Studio, it gives following error:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'user' must appear on element 'db:oracle-config'
```

What is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, upgrading to 3.6 should solve the problem.
[mule-jira-7708](http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/mule-jira-MULE-7708-Database-Oracle-Configuration-still-requires-user-and-password-attributes-when-in-td5721168.html)

Alternatively you can try the workaround below:

```html
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" useXaTransactions="true" dataSource-ref="dataSource" user="${oracle.jdbc.user}" password="${oracle.jdbc.password}" doc:name="Oracle Configuration">
    <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="5" acquireIncrement="2"/>
</db:oracle-config>

<spring:beans>               
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown" name="Bean">
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <spring:property name="url" value="${oracle.jdbc.url}"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```